# Rails 4 - paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out rails 4.

I have a project model and a project_question model.

Project question belongs to project.

I want a form which redirects to the project page after a question is submitted. I keep getting directed back to a list of projects, rather than the specific project in respect of which a question has been asked. I am struggling to figure out how to learn rails.

In my project_question_form I have:

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

      <div class="header-project">What would you like to know?</div>

      <%= render 'form' %>
      <div class="formminor">
      <%= link_to 'Back', projects_path(@project) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the bracketed bit in the "Back" link to go back to the project page that the user was on when they clicked 'ask a question'. Instead, the user is taken back to the page which lists an index of all projects.

In my ask a question form, I have:

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <%= simple_form_for :project_questions do |f| %>
              <%= f.input :project_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: @project_question_id} %>
              <%= f.input :title, label: 'Question:',  :label_html => {:class => 'question-title'}, placeholder: 'Type your question here', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 4, class: 'response-project'} %>
              <%= f.input :content, label: 'Is there any context or other information?', :label_html => {:class => 'question-title'}, placeholder: 'Context might help to answer your question', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 5, class: 'response-project'} %>

          <br><br><br>
              <%= f.button :submit, 'Send!', :class => "cpb" %>

    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
resources :projects do
    resources :project_questions do
      resources :project_answers
    end
  end
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?  I have tried using (@project_id) and (@project.id) in place of (@project) in the first form. None of those alternatives work.

My projects_controller has:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  #layout :projects_student_layout

  before_action :authenticate_user!  

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects


    #can i have more than one index? do i need to change something in the routes? if i want to list the related projects and the expiring projects - how do i do that within one index?

    #is there a way to order these, so that for educators they are in order of course and for students they are in order of next milestone date?
    #@projects.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # def index2
 #    @projects = Project.find_xxx_xx
 #  end

  def list
    @projects = Project.find(:all)
  end

  def toggle_draft
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.draft = true
    @project.save
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
    #authorise @project

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @creator = User.find(@project.creator_id)
    @creator_profile = @creator.profile

    #@approver_profile = User.find(@project.educator_id).profile #educators are the only people who approve projects
#    if profile == 'studnet'
    #@approval = @project.approval

 #   @invitations = @project.project_invitations

  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    #authorise @project
    @project = Project.new
    @project.scope = Scope.new
    @project.scope.datum = Datum.new
    @project.scope.material = Material.new
    @project.scope.mentoring = Mentoring.new
    @project.scope.participant = Participant.new
    @project.scope.funding = Funding.new
    @project.scope.ethic = Ethic.new
    @project.scope.group_research = GroupResearch.new
    @project.scope.backgroundip = Backgroundip.new
    @project.scope.result = Result.new
    @project.scope.finalise = Finalise.new

  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    #authorise @project
    @project =Project.find(params[:id])    
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    #authorise @project
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.creator_id = current_user.id
    @project.users << current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project }, flash[:notice] = "Project saved"
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    #authorise @project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.creator_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    #authorise @project

    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(
      :id, :title, :description, :video_proposal, :link_to_video_proposal,
      :expiry_date_for_sponsor_interest,  :motivation, :approach,
      :completion_date, :start_date, :industry_id,  :recurring_project,
      :frequency, :date_for_student_invitation, :date_for_student_interest, :closed, :student_objective, 
      :industry_relevance, :hero_image, :project_id,
      project_question_attributes: [:title, :content, :user_id, :project_id,
      project_answer_attributes: [:answer, :project_question_id]],
      scope_attributes: [:id, :project_id, :data, :material, :mentoring, :participant, :funding, :ethic, :group, :result, :disclosure, :finalise,
                         :if_mentoring, :if_participant, :if_funding, :if_ethic, :if_group_research, :if_backgroundip, :if_datum, :if_material,
                         datum_attributes: [:id, :prim_sec, :qual_quant, :survey, :survey_link, :experiment, :other_type, :other_description,
                                           :confidential, :data_description, :scope_id],
                         material_attributes: [:id, :mattype, :description, :scope_id],
                         mentoring_attributes: [:id, :frequency, :description, :scope_id],
                         funding_attributes: [:id,  :expenses, :honorarium, :financing, :currency, :size, :amount_expenses, :amount_honorarium,
                                 :comment, :amount_principal_financing, :return_on_finance, :period_of_return, :expense_description, :amount_expenses_pennies, :amount_honorarium_pennies, :amount_principal_financing_pennies,
                                               :amount_expenses_currency, :scope_id],
                         participant_attributes: [:id,  :title, :description, :location, :costs, :participation_cost,
                                                   :eligibility, :eligibility_criteria, :currency, :participation_cost_pennies, :participation_cost_currency,
                                                   :location_specific ],
                         group_research_attributes: [:id, :number_of_group_members, :scope_id],
                         ethic_attributes: [:id, :obtained, :date_expected, :ethics_comment, :ethics_policy_link, :scope_id],
                         result_attributes: [:id, :report, :standard_licence, :bespoke_licence, :option, :assignment, :other_outcome,
                                             :consulting, :link_to_bespoke_licence, :description],
                         disclosure_attributes: [:id, :allusers, :publicity, :limitedorganisation, :limitedindustry, :limiteduser, :approveddisclosure],
                         backgroundip_attributes: [:id, :scope_id, :copyright, :design, :patent, :trademark, :geographical_indication,
                                                   :trade_secret, :other, :identifier_copyright, :identifier_design, :identifier_patent,
                                                   :identifier_trademark, :identifier_geographical_indication, :identifier_trade_secret,
                                                   :identifier_other, :description, :registered_owner, :unregistered_interest, :conditions,
                                                   :pbr, :identifier_pbr ],

                         finalise_attributes: [:id, :draft, :reminder, :reminder_date, :finalised_at, :scope_id]
                          ]
      )


    end
```

When I bundle exec rake routes (as suggested below), I get a lot of routes for all the models. The ones that include project_question are:

```
project_answers#destroy
                    project_project_questions GET      /projects/:project_id/project_questions(.:format)                                               project_questions#index
                                              POST     /projects/:project_id/project_questions(.:format)                                               project_questions#create
                 new_project_project_question GET      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/new(.:format)                                           project_questions#new
                edit_project_project_question GET      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:id/edit(.:format)                                      project_questions#edit
                     project_project_question GET      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:id(.:format)                                           project_questions#show
                                              PATCH    /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:id(.:format)                                           project_questions#update
                                              PUT      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:id(.:format)                                           project_questions#update
                                              DELETE   /projects/:project_id/project_questions/:id(.:format)                                           project_questions#destroy
```

Chad's route suggestion:

```
projects GET      /projects(.:format)                                                                             projects#index
                                              POST     /projects(.:format)                                                                             projects#create
                                  new_project GET      /projects/new(.:format)                                                                         projects#new
                                 edit_project GET      /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                    projects#edit
                                      project GET      /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                         projects#show
                                              PATCH    /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                         projects#update
                                              PUT      /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                         projects#update
                                              DELETE   /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                         projects#destroy
```

My project_question controller:

```
class ProjectQuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /project_questions
  # GET /project_questions.json
  def index
    @project_questions = ProjectQuestion.all
  end

  # GET /project_questions/1
  # GET /project_questions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /project_questions/new
  def new
    @project_question = ProjectQuestion.new
    @project_id = params[:project_id]
    @project_question.project_answers[0] = ProjectAnswer.new

  end

  # GET /project_questions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /project_questions
  # POST /project_questions.json
  def create
    @project_question = ProjectQuestion.new(project_question_params)
    @project_question.project_id = project_question_params[:project_id]


    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project_question, notice: 'Project question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project_question }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project_question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /project_questions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /project_questions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_question.update(project_question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project_question, notice: 'Project question was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project_question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /project_questions/1
  # DELETE /project_questions/1.json
  def destroy
    @project_question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_questions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project_question
      @project_question = ProjectQuestion.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_question_params
      params[:project_question].permit(:id, :title, :content, :project_id, :user_id,
      project_answer_atttibutes: [:id, :answer, :project_question_id, :user_id]
      )
    end
end
```

This link is in my projects show page:

```
  <%= link_to 'Ask a question', new_project_project_question_path(:project_id => @project.id) %> <% end %>
```

Comment: please show your projects controller. I believe you have not defined the `@project`

Comment: Pavan - my projects_contorller is posted. do you also suggest i post the project_question controller?

Comment: From which controller action you are calling `project_question_form`?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't understand the question. In my project_questions_form to ask a new question, I'm trying to click on a link called back that will go back to the project in respect of which the project_question is being asked

Comment: I think your `@project` is empty in the view

Comment: I mean which action renders the `project_question_form` actually?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand that question either. On my projects show page I have a link, to ask a new question. That link goes to the project_question_form page

Comment: Ok.Update your post with your `products show` page

Comment: The problem might be in your `project_questions ` controller, can you add it to the question?

Comment: I don't have a products model or products show

Comment: You said "On my projects show page I have a link" which page?

Comment: that's in my projects show page

Comment: Gabrielhilal - i added the controller to the bottom of the page

Comment: Pavan - thanks for trying to help. You asked me for my product page. I've copied the link from my projects show page to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try:

```
project_path(@project_id)
```

Then, if that doesn't work, then you need to make sure that when you go from the project page to the ask a question page, you're passing `@project.id` as a parameter called `project_id`.

Comment: Hi Chad, how do I know if it is displaying a valid route? The browser url shows the project id when I'm on the question form.I don't know how to check if project.nil? == true or where to try that. I know the project is saved because I have been checking it in the console.

Comment: I tried the rake routes | grep projects_path, but it didn't produce any results, I tried it without _path and I got the output that I pasted in the question

Comment: OK, so that means that you are not getting an actual route when you call `projects_path`.  You should be calling `project_path`, I think but then you need to be passing an ID to it.  You are going to have to check if `@project.nil?` and only use the `project_path(@project)` if it is present. If it should always be there but isn't, that's part of your problem too.

Comment: When you said elsewhere, "I get this error: No route matches {:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id] That isn't correct"  That actually meant it *WAS* correct. You are getting an actual route when you call `project_path(@project)` but the interpreter is squawking at you for sending it nil.

Comment: How do I approach that problem?

Comment: Thank you- how did you figure that out?

Comment: Well, first I knew you were not getting a real path from `projects_path`. So we checked `rake routes` and found it should be `project`, not `projects`. Also we found that it expects an `:id`.  So we went to check what the :id is, and you are sending `@project` on the new question page.  So I wanted to see in the project_question controller what you set `@project` to, which was nothing. You set `@project_id` to `params[:project_id]`. 

Answer (score 0):

You should use `project_path(@project)` instead of `projects_path(@project)`.

Comment: Thanks anyway Yogesh, but when I try that, I get this error: No route matches {:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
That isn't correct

Comment: Ok, so how are you defining your routes ?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I would suggest run 
`bundle exec rake routes`

Then get determined your path name and required parameters. Based on your problem we can't answer correct path straight forward. So best practice is using rake routes.

Comment: How do I determine my path?

Comment: as I answered when you run rake routes on your terminal you will see list of available routes in respect of their controller and action.  And there will be list of required param names.

Comment: What do I do with the output of that function? I copied the bits of rake routes to the question above. Am I supposed to copy all of those to the link to "back" line?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
project_path(@project_question_id)
```

Comment: Thanks Sebi. I'm afraid that also goes back to the index of all the projects (which I don't understand at all). Thanks anyway, I'm trying to find a way to send it back to the project show page itself

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `@project` in your `new` action of your `ProjectQuestionsController` as below

```
def new
    @project_question = ProjectQuestion.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) #here
    @project_question.project_answers[0] = ProjectAnswer.new
end
```

and change your `link_to` as

```
<%= link_to 'Back', project_path(@project) %>
```

Comment: Is the 2nd line of the new action instead of this line:     @project_id = params[:project_id]

Comment: I don't understand what either of those is doing - is there something wrong with the way I have it with Chad's suggestion?